# Some tags of the xml aren't deserialized

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

So I have this class generated with xsd.exe, when I deserialize the XML into my object it doesn't read all the attributes. Looks like the last attribute within a tree isn't read.

This is one of object's class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
public partial class relation : myXml {

/// <remarks/>
public object a;

/// <remarks/>
public object b;

/// <remarks/>
public object c;

/// <remarks/>
public object d;

/// <remarks/>
public object f;

/// <remarks/>
public object g;

/// <remarks/>
public object h;

/// <remarks/>
public object i;

/// <remarks/>
public object j;
}
```

Example XML:

```
<z id="Fo">
    <attributes>
        <Relation>1<Relation>
        <YVersion>16<YVersion>
        <W>
            <a>1</a>
            <b>2</b>
            <c>3</c>
            <d>4</d>
        </W>
    </attributes>
</z>
```

When I debug, my Object with all the deserialized XML has all the nodes until the node W including node W and it's parameters however the below nodes aren't deserialized somehow, in this case nodes A, B, C and D.

Regards,

Hugo

Comment: I suggest you to google "XML to model C#" you'll find better creators than XSD. And they are online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like W is a complex type, while Relation & YVersion are just integers. you need a default constructor on your attributes object that instantiates any complex types. Also any of these other types you want to serialize that have complex types as properties need to be instantiated in a default constructor for the serializer to be able to work with them.

So for example your attributes class would look like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Attributes
{
  public int Relation {get; set;}

public int YVersion {get; set;}

  public MyType W {get; set;}

  public Attributes()
  {
     W = new MyType();
  }

}
```

Keep in mind that you can't pass any parameters to the constructor because the serializer won't have any objects to pass to it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a shot

Comment: Shouldn't it work with a simple get;set ?

As I do not have types for my types, they are all defined as object, I can't instate one object of type object right

Comment: you can instantiate an object. Looking at your xml though "W" is not a plain object. It's got properties name A, B, C, D which appear to be integers or maybe strings. Additionally, on your XML Relation appears to be an integer, not an object with a bunch of sub-objects. You may want to back up and try doing this with a simpler XML without the xsd tool so you understand what's going on.

Comment: I am marking your response as accepted as it kinda pointed me to look at the classes generated by xsd where indeed was the problem. actualy what solved the problem here was adding [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("W", typeof(W), Namespace="W.xsd")] where I'd expect it to be on the XML tree.
Thanks!